# When refresh the page https is changed to http

Tags: php, apache

My website uses SSL certification.
So when the user comes to some page, this page should redirect him to main page.
But when it does, it redirects to changed certification page to `http`.

I'm using the following code to redirect user:

```
<?php
$url = SITE_PROTOCOL . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$SomeClass->someMethod($query['id']);
header("Refresh:0; url=" . SITE_PROTOCOL . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . SITE_PREFIX);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: you should not do this in a php page, but an Apache config such as `.htaccess`

Comment: @smith What you mean 'do this' ?

Comment: rewrite\redirect the urls to `https`

Comment: @smith Are you talking about this `#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro`?

Comment: It is a much better idea to do this in your .htaccess file rather than on your PHP file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a .htaccess file for Apache.

Simply upload (or edit an existing) .htaccess file to the root of your site (/var/www or public_html usually) with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

RewriteEngine will redirect all HTTP traffic to port 80 of your domain (example.com in this example) to the new domain specified at the bottom with https. Make sure to input your own domain to the above code where necessary.

This will only force HTTPS standards. An explanation for your browsing being redirected to http is that links on your website are http and not https. This will either require a manual fix, or if you are using a popular CMS you may be able to find the URL variable somewhere in the code/admin panel.